# How to track user activity and click on another app?

Tags: android, accessibility

Generally, i want to give blind people the ability for someone else to DO SOMETHING ON ANOTHER APP, and my app will track his clicks, and reproduce it later for the blind person.

I want to track what UI elements the user has clicked on for some apps, and keep it into a file, so later i can reproduce it inside my own app.

I want to give the user the ability to show me where he wants to click, save it into a file, and reproduce it later.

Seems like it's impossible for an Android app to do it - as each one is running on a separate virtual box,

so it's possible just by forking Android OS itself,

1. Do you think about a better solution for it (without forking)?
2. Do you know in which Android repo can i find the user activity (so i can track it) ?
   https://github.com/aosp-mirror

Very similar to what Selenium gives us as developers...

Thank a lot for the helpers!

Initially tried to do it using the AccessibilityService class, but it doesn't look like there is a way.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)